# Isolated nodes in quanteda::textplot_network() output and how to remove/drop them

Tags: r, quanteda

Twitter data is being analyzed by plotting author handles (@mentions) using the textplot_network() function in quanteda (v1.3.4). However, plot shows some isolated (non-connected) nodes as well.

Would like to know if this is because no other author handle (@mention) occurs with one of such nodes basis the frequency set in the function call. Also is there a way to remove them from the frequency co-occurence matrix (fcm) so that these then do not appear in the  plot.

```
require(data.table)
require(quanteda)
require(stringr)

not_clause_1 <- fread("final_query_output.csv", header = TRUE, skip = 0L, 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, select = c("Date","Full Text","Page 
Type","Country", "Gender", "Author","Author City","Author Country","Author 
State","City","County","Topics"))

setnames(not_clause_1, c("Page Type", "Full Text", "Author Country", 
"Author State", "Author City"), c("Page_Type", "Full_Text", 
"Author_Country", "Author_State", "Author_City"))

corpus1 <- corpus(not_clause_1$Full_Text, docnames = 
paste(not_clause_1$Author, not_clause_1$idx, sep = "(")) ## using 
quanteda's corpus

tokens1 <- quanteda::tokens(tolower(corpus1), what = "word", remove_numbers 
= TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE, remove_separators = 
TRUE, remove_url = TRUE, remove_hyphens = TRUE)

tokens1 <- tokens_remove(tokens1, stopwords("english"))

set.seed(12345)
mydfm <- dfm(tokens1, tolower = TRUE)

mentions_dfm <- dfm_select(mydfm, pattern = "@*") ## select only the author 
handles beginning with @ ##
mentions_fcm <- fcm(mentions_dfm)
top_mention_names <- names(topfeatures(mentions_dfm, min(150, 
length(featnames(mentions_dfm)))))
topmention_fcm <- fcm_select(mentions_fcm, pattern = top_mention_names, 
selection = "keep")

size <- log(colSums(fcm_select(topmention_fcm, top_mention_names)))

textplot_network(topmention_fcm, vertex_size = size/max(size)*3, edge_color 
= "blue", edge_alpha = 0.8, edge_size = 3, omit_isolated = TRUE)
```

As described in the summary of the problem, I would like to know how certain authors eg: @moonbow_living figure in the fcm without any connected nodes and also if there is a way to drop them from the fcm just before calling texplot_network().

Added a link for downloading the base data and network plot which has isolated nodes:[reference files](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0a3fc0deb7fcbf2be027d35dcad3235020190112082933/53158c32e6bb268a108caedf1a9bff4e20190112082933/af6894)